# wrong calculation using php

Tags: php

65 + 10 = 75

75 x 15 x 686 = 771750

771750 / 365 / 30 = **70.479** this is correct answer

and this code showing answer wrong

this is wrong answer of this code **74.400**

how can i solve it please help me
thanks

```
$res = 65+10*15*686/365/30; //Adding the two values and placing the added result to 'res' variable

<?php //Starting of php 
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))//if the submit button has pressed
    {
    $days = $_POST['days']; //Getting Value of first integer from add.html
    $yeardays1 = $_POST['yeardays1']; //Getting Value of Second integer from add.html
    $yeardays = $_POST['yeardays1']; //Getting Value of Second integer from add.html
    $basicsalary = $_POST['basicsalary']; //Getting Value of Second integer from add.html
    $allowsalary = $_POST['allowsalary']; //Getting Value of Second integer from add.html
    $res = (($basicsalary + $allowsalary)* $days * $yeardays1) / $yeardays /$monthdays;


    echo number_format((round($res, 1)),3);

    }
    //Ending of php
    ?>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about learning school arithmetic

Comment: You should be aware that all values retrieved from $_POST are strings. Whilst PHP will have a good go at casting them to integers for you, you should do this explicitly to avoid unexpected results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your operator precedence logic is wrong, time to get back to some basic mathematics (*BODMAS*). However for your desired precedence you can use

```
<?php
        $res = ((65+10)*15*686)/365/30;
        echo 'Added Result:';

       echo number_format((round($res, 1)),3);

?>
```

> Added Result:70.500

**[Fiddle](http://codepad.org/NZWsTnMg)** based on your variables

Comment: The only correct answer from all this swarm pointing to `round()` while whole logic is wrong..

Comment: @hanky im using like that but it is not working  $res = (($basicsalary+$allowsalary)*$days*$yeardays1)/$yeardays/$monthdays;

Comment: Please update your code with those variables in place and their values in place

Comment: i update my code please check it

Comment: Works even with those. http://codepad.org/NZWsTnMg

Comment: it is showing error Warning: Division by zero in
print.php
on line 162

Comment: Then you are dividing things by zero, simple as that. Either `$yeardays` is not initialized or `$monthdays` isn't.

Comment: oh sorry my mistake i got my answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just used `round()` function, so result is correct. Read about it here php.net/round

Change precision to get more digits.

Now I see that there is much bigger problem. Expression `10*15*686/365/30` will be evaluated first, then `65` will be added. So your proposed result is incorrect. Use `75*15*686/365/30` to get your result.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using `round` AND `number_format` . Choose one of them.

```
<?php 
    $res = ( 65 + 10 ) * 15 * 686 / 365 / 30; //Adding the two values and placing the added result to 'res' variable
    echo 'Added Result:';

    echo number_format($res,3); /* 70.479 */
    //Ending of php
?>
```

.+ your algorithm was false.

Answer (score 0):

Php follows the same rule as we study in the basic mathematics BODMAS

The calculations works on the basis of the priority of the operators

Use the below code

```
<?php
        $res = ((65+10)*15*686)/365/30;
        echo 'Added Result:';

       echo number_format((round($res, 1)),3);

?>
```